# SQL Server increment two tables in an update

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, SQL is NOT my strong point, as you'll see. I have one table that keeps track of the next item number, by some type, like so:

```
declare @maxs as table 
(
    Equip int,
    NextId int
);

-- initial id values
insert into @maxs (Equip, NextId) values (400, 40);
insert into @maxs (Equip, NextId) values (500, 50);
```

If I create an item of type '400' then the next Id is 40, and that should be incremented to 41. In a case of a single add, that's easy enough. Our program does adds in batch, so here is my problem.

```
declare @t as table (Id int, Equip int, Descr varchar(20));

-- simulates the batch processing
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (400, 'Item 1');
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (400, 'Item 2');
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (500, 'Item 3');

-- generate the new id's in batch
UPDATE t
SET Id = (SELECT m.NextId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Equip ORDER BY t.Equip))
FROM @t t
INNER JOIN @maxs m ON m.Equip = t.Equip

SELECT * FROM @t
```

This results in both Item 1 and Item 2 having the same Id because only 1 row is returned for 400, so ROW_NUMBER is the same for both. I need to be able to increment the NextId value in @maxs as well as update the entry in @t so that the second row that joins into the 400 value in @maxs will have the next value (almost like a x++ reference in c#). Is there a clean way to do that in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is not dealing with incementing numbers on sql server at all. simply use an identity column and let sql server do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Some objects need contiguous numbering by requirement. Eg, statement numbering has to start from 1 and increment contiguously (and this for each account number).

Comment: @TT I agree, but getting numbers to behave that way in sql server can be tricky, especially in multi users environment, hence my recommendation. Most of the time an identity column is the best option.

Comment: We do have identity columns in all of our tables. This is a secondary column that we use for item number, just to make our job more complicated I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with JOIN and nested select

```
declare @t as table (Id int, Equip int, Descr varchar(20));

-- simulates the batch processing
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (400, 'Item 1');
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (400, 'Item 2');
insert into @t (Equip, Descr) values (500, 'Item 3');

-- generate the new id's in batch

UPDATE t
SET
    Id = t.Equip + s.RowNum
FROM @t t
    JOIN (select Equip, 
                 Descr, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Equip ORDER BY Equip) RowNum 
          from @t) s
    on t.Equip = s.Equip and t.Descr = s.Descr

select * from @t
```

And if possible, try to switch from table variable to temporary table

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The var table was just to make the example easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Equip ORDER BY t.Equip) as seqnum
      FROM @t t
UPDATE t
    SET
        Id = m.NextId + seqnum
    FROM toupdate t INNER JOIN
         @maxs m
         ON m.Equip = t.Equip;
```

I'm not sure this is a *good idea*, though.  It is better to use `identity` columns to identify each row.  There are definitely some cases, though, where numbering within a group is useful as a secondary key (for instance, line items on an invoice).

Comment: This should work too. I chose the other answer because I had tried something similar which was closer to that answer. I do have identity columns in my tables. This is just one weird scenario where we use a unique item number based on other criteria of the item.